# Vuex store returns [__ob__: Observer] in created() method instead of string

Tags: typescript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vuex store that contains a `username` string. It's initially set to and empty string but every user, new or old, will be assigned a random string initially.

I want to allow users to change their username. I also want to display the username as the initial `value` in the text input.

However, the initial value is just an empty string. When logging `username` in created (or any lifecycle methods after), I get `[__ob__: Observer]`. If I set a timeout of 500ms, I get the expected string but this is too messy for me.

Here's the relevant code:

```js
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent>
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="usernameField"
    />
    <button @click="usernameUpdate()">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
  import { namespace } from 'vuex-class'

  const AccountGetter = namespace('account').Getter
  const AccountAction = namespace('account').Action

  const AppProps = Vue.extend({
    data: () => {
      return {
        usernameField: ''
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.usernameField = this.username
      console.log(this.username)
      // returns [__ob__: Observer]
      // using setTimeout() works though
    },
    methods: {
      async usernameUpdate() {
        // working code using updateUserProfile
      }
    }
  })

  export default class VerifyGame extends AppProps {
    @AccountGetter username!: String;
    @AccountAction updateUserProfile
  }
</script>
```

Vuex store:

```js
// also includes updateUserProfile mutation

import { AccountState, RootState } from './types'
import { GetterTree } from 'vuex'

type AccountGetter = GetterTree<AccountState, RootState>

export const state: AccountState = {
  username: ''
}

export const getters: AccountGetter = {
  username: state => state.username
}
```

Comment: That implies `username` is set asynchronously after the hook is run. If your code relies on `username`'s most recent value, use a watcher on it to observe changes.

Answer (score 1):

[**ob**: Observer] is an object. The value you need would be in a variable under it. You can get the desired variable by using  this.username.varname.

I would recommend that you use something like below for your vuex. And use the addUserData mutation to update your username. The data in it can be accessed as this.$store.state.userData.username

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        userData: {
            username: ""
        }
    },
    getters: {},
    mutations: {
        addUserData(state, data) {
            // state.userData.assign(data)
            state.userData = Object.assign({}, data);
        }
    },
    actions: {}
});
```